# Getting Started with Contributing to Zurb Foundation

Tags: gruntjs, zurb-foundation

I have an interest in contributing to the Zurb Foundation project via GitHub. However, I can't figure out how to build the project. I have successfully cloned the repository from https://github.com/zurb/foundation.git.

When I run `grunt` from the command-line, I receive an error that says:

```
grunt-cli: The grunt command line interface. (v0.1.11)

Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt.
```

I then run `npm install grunt` and `npm install grunt-cli` from the command line. After I do this, I receive an error that says:

```
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'highlight.js'
Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.
```

However, when I open Gruntfile.js, I can see that a "default" task does exist. What am I doing wrong? I would really like to figure out how to build Zurb Foundation in my local environment so that I can begin contributing.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open terminal and enter `npm i` in Zurb Foundation folder. This command will install all modules including `highlight.js`. After that try `grunt` again.